# Using user:pass-protected Geoserver layer as a WFS service in ArcGIS Earth?

Tags: geoserver, wfs, arcgis-earth

I am able to load a WFS layer from a Geoserver in QGIS. Note that the layer needs a login to see. If I try to load it in ArcGIS Earth however, I get an error. I think the issue is that I don't see a user login option when choosing the OGC WFS Option in ArcGIS Earth:

[image]

Anyone know how to store the credentials, or some sort of workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like an issue with your path. If the path is valid, you should get a popup asking for a username and password:

[image]

Verify that the path to the service is valid.